# Await is not waiting to read data from file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-modules, fs

I write the following code to read the data from the file and push into array. But attachments.length is printing 0 first and then data is loaded and print.

```
const fs=require('fs');
const util=require('util');
const files=['t1.csv','t2.csv','t3.csv'];
async getdata(){
     const read=util.promisify(fs.readFile);
     let attachments = [];
     async function run(file){
         let data=await read(file);
         attachments.push(data);
     } 
     for(let file of files){
         await run(file);
     }
     console.log(attachments.length);//should print 3
}
```

How to load the data first and then push correctly.

**Edit:** change the some part of code to use await. But loop break after first iteration without giving any error neither print my attchments.length .

**Edit 2:** problem resolved. Calling function should also need to be await. Thanks every one.

Comment: You have to `await` for the asynchronous `run` function to complete the process.

Comment: Note that `await` can only be used inside an `async` function, so if your code is running in the global scope, you can't just do `await run('/home/nadeem/Desktop/test.csv')`.

Comment: kindly see my edit. I am new in node js. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `run()` should be awaited as well in this case,
see [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

One approach is using [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
(async file => {
    let data = await read(file);
    console.log(data);
    attachments.push(data);
})('/home/nadeem/Desktop/test.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call an `async` function, it returns a promise that will eventually resolve with the value returned by the function (or reject with an uncaught exception thrown from within the function).

So you're trying to log the number of attachments before the `run ()` function has finished. Here's what you need:

```js
run('/home/nadeem/Desktop/test.csv')
  .then(() => console.log(attachments.length))
```